# Tool to expand latex commands in text

Tags: scripts

Is there a script out there to expand LaTeX commands in a tex source?

I am submitting a manuscript source and I need a tool that expands a LaTeX command because I do not want some commands to appear in the source.
Example source:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\modified}[2]{#2}
\begin{document}
    \modified{Old long
     % Possible comments 
    Text} {New
    correct 
    Text % with comments
    }
\end{document}
```

After executing the command, I would like an output like this

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\modified}[2]{#2}
\begin{document}
    New
    correct 
    Text % with comments
\end{document}
```

If such a script doesn't exist, can you suggest tools to write one? For example, is there a Perl package that is LaTeX-aware?

Comment: Just to be clear: You're looking for a tool that modifies the *input file*, right?

Comment: Well, this is rather a task for `Perl` or `sed`, in my point of view

Comment: Yes, the tool would modify the input file.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no such tool. A generic TeX macro expander would expand all macros unless it encounters something unexpandable (usually a TeX primitive or input tokens). This kind of output would be plain unreadable.

So I suggest that you write your command replacement tool yourself in a script language you know well (perl and sed are good suggestions for this task, python and emacs-lisp come also to my mind).

Comment: I am more thinking of a tool that would take a list of commands and expand only those. I will probably write it myself

Answer (score 1):

Your MWE suggests that your `\modified` macro is here to hide former versions.

Then a very simple approach is simply to comment out the old versions in lines starting with a distinctive pattern, say

```
%private
```

or

```
%!!
```

Then use sed utility for example to remove all private lines, something like

```
sed '/^%!!/d' foo.tex > bar.tex
```

You can also do something like `\catcode1 14` and use `^^A` at the start of the private lines then

```
sed '/^^^A/d' foo.tex > bar.tex
```

should work.

Comment: one can also use an auxiliary tex file to do a read/write obtaining what `sed` does, but except if you want this also on systems with no `sed` like line utility, I don't see the point. But it all depends on what is your exact use case, which is not completely clear from your posted question.

Comment: I usually set the `modified` command to display a strikedout old text and, just before submitting, change the command to completely ignore the old text. I wanted a solution that doesn't require me to manually go through the text hunting for these commands.

Comment: I you follow some simple mark-up rules you can considerably make easier the job later. For example you could use decide to do something like `\catcode 1 9 `, then `\modified{^^A nothing else on same line`,  `^^A as start of line` and put the closing brace `}` at start of its line. Then you only need to grep for `\^^A.*` and remove the text matching that patterns. They are many ways, but if you have already used `\modified` type macros all over the place without any extra mark-up discipline, then it is harder using text editor search/replace.

Comment: 0 votes after two years? +1

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner much appreciated `:)`. I have no idea what this post is all about apart from the fact that I actually do that in my xint package: I use ``%!`` to signal private comments which are trimmed when actually building up the CTAN upload... (I used ``%÷`` for long time, but using utf-8 make some difficulties with how my active `%`  now act in my private builds, so finally ``%!``). I remove them via ``sed`` similar as in my answer here.

Comment: I like the elegant and yet easy method. I also prefer style guides which enable you to use search and replace